# Elastic Search Term and Terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm studying Elastic Search queries. I can not understand this query:

```
{
    "term" : { "user" : { "term" : "kimchy", "boost" : 2.0 } }
}
```

I've read this article but it's not clear:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

1- What is the second "term"?
2- What is the usage of boost?
3- How to use term or terms to have this query:
a field named "title" must contains: "key1" and "key2" or "key3" and "key4"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First `term` is the type of the query. Second  `term` is the parameter of this query.
2. boost is used to make this query more relevant than the default, in case you have several queries (the default boost value is 1.0)
3. There are several ways to achieve this. One of them would be `query_string`, another a `bool` query. Here is an example of query_string:

> ```
> {
>     "query_string" : {
>         "default_field" : "user",
>         "query" : "(key1 AND key2) OR (key3 AND key4)"
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: If `user` field is analyzed, this query may not work depending on `key1`, `key2`, `key3` and `key4` values if he really wants to work with terms. Maybe a bool query with `term` queries may be "safer". Besides this, nice answer!